# enable required field validator only the selected gridview row

Tags: asp.net

I have a 5 rows in gridview. Gridview have textbox with validator for the 5 rows and last one link button. When I click on the selected row  link button all the rows required field validator message showing. I need only the selected row show the validator message

```
<ItemTemplate> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="25px"
        TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%#Eval("Remarks") %>' /> 
   <br />
   <table width="100px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
      <tr>
         <td style="border-width: 0;"> 
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRemarks" runat="server" 
                  ControlToValidate="txtRemarks" ValidationGroup="isolateDog" 
                  Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                   ErrorMessage="Please enter remarks">
             </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: just simple i select a row in the gridview that validator should display if i did not enter anyvalue. It should not validate other row validation message kindly help

Comment: yeah i got the problem however if you don't share your code then i can't answer your question as i'll not be able to find out what's wrong or what changes are to be done.

Comment: <ItemTemplate>                                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="25px" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%#Eval("Remarks") %>' />
<br /> <table width="100px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr><td style="border-width: 0;"> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRemarks" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRemarks" ValidationGroup="isolateDog" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter remarks"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: can you please share your complete code within the gridview, on which linkbutton your validations are being fired.